# How to remove child one to many related records in EF code first database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Well, I have one-to-many related model:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is clear `Parent.Children` and remove related child entities from database. I've already tried:

**Database context class:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Children)
            .WithOptional()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

this works fine, but I still have redundant records in database with `Parent_Id = null` fields when I do

```
parent.Children.Clear();
repository.InsertOrUpdate(parent);
```

in my repository class. Also the same behavior is when I do:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasMany(pr => pr.Children)
            .WithOptional(ri => ri.Parent)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

with additional `Parent` property in `Child` class

```
public class Child
{
    ...
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

or when I do

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.Parent)
            .WithMany(p => p.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.Parent_Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

with additional Parent_Id property in `Child` class

```
public class Child
{
     ...
     public int Parent_Id { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

**So, how can I configure cascade deleting correctly? Or how should I supposed to remove those child entities? I assume this is casual task but I'm just missing something.**

Comment: Can you post some more code?  Maybe the full contents of your `OnModelCreating()`?  When I copy-and-paste your entities and your first mapping attempt (and set `Id` as the key property for both entities), deletes are cascading correctly for me.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Cascading delete has no effect here because you don't delete the `parent` but just call `InsertOrUpdate`. The correct procedure is to delete the children one-by-one, like so for example:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var parent = context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children)
        .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == parentId);

    foreach (var child in parent.Children.ToList())
        context.Children.Remove(child);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Surely with cascade delete on you dont need to delete the children individually?

Comment: @kirsteng: Cascading delete means that the children are deleted **if** you delete the parent. But in this question no parent is deleted. So, cascading delete does not apply to this scenario.

Comment: instead of foreaching all of the "child" objects, just say `context.Children.RemoveRange(parent.Children.ToArray())` that way the DbContext doesn't have to do as much work checking each time you call Remove. This may not be a big performance problem for deletes, but I've noticed a huge difference when adding items one at a time when I tested adding 100k records using `context.Children.Add(child)` in a for loop.

Comment: Of course, you want to make sure that sucking all of the children into memory doesn't blow up the memory in your process space.

Comment: cascade delete works in this situation, at least when using EF Core :)

Comment: @Konrad Thanks for the hint. In my case, I had to alter DB-schema to have `ON DELETE CASCADE` and  generate DB-models again to have `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` in them.

Comment: oh this sucks so much. You mean you suggest to pull all children into the app first and then delete them? Is this what we have come to?

Answer (score 117):

In EF6 a faster way to do the operation is...

```
 context.Children.RemoveRange(parent.Children)
```

Comment: It is a faster way to code but in terms of performance, is it really faster? If I want to delete all children under parent with `parent.Id == 10`, and my `Child` class has 100 fields and haven't loaded to memory yet, it seems inefficient to use `RemoveRange` because the program will have to load `parent.Children` with all 100 fields by default.

Comment: @VCD it's faster than calling context.Children.Remove(child) for each child but not as fast as running sql "DELETE FROM Children where parentId=@parentId"

Comment: How would you go about finding the parent, if the only info you have is the child Id?

Comment: @guyfromfargo in EF something like `var child = context.Children.Single(f=>f.Id==childId); var parent = context.Parents.Single(f=>f.Id==child.ParentId);`

Comment: @SamSippe when you've got the child, and your model is correct, you should be able to get the parent by simply accessing it's `Parent` property. Of course this doesn't work if lazy-loading is disabled.

Answer (score 10):

This is called "deleting orphans".

[Can EF automatically delete data that is orphaned, where the parent is not deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835439/can-ef-automatically-delete-data-that-is-orphaned-where-the-parent-is-not-delet)

I don't know how it works in EF6 but in EF Core it works fine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete so you don't necessarily need to delete the parent for cascades to work.

[Delete orphans examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#delete-orphans-examples)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now as the first link exactly describes how to solve the issue.   The OP needs to add the parent Id to the child as a FK and then set up the Identifying Relation using the approach in that link.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing to

```
 public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
```

because virtual is needed to get lazy loading.
as explained 
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784796/entity-framework-virtual-properties)

I think your parent.Children.clear isnt working because the Children have not been loaded

Comment: In my case (ASP.NET core 2 / EF Core), I've tested and this was not the solution

Answer (score 1):

If your object is self-referencing, you can delete both many-to-many and one-to-many children using the method below. Just remember to call db.SaveChanges() afterwards :)

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Object obj = this.db.Objects.Find(id);
    this.DeleteObjectAndChildren(obj);
    this.db.Objects.Remove(obj);
    this.db.SaveChanges();
    return this.Json(new { success = true });
}

/// <summary>
/// This deletes an object and all children, but does not commit changes to the db.
///  - MH @ 2016/08/15 14:42
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parent">
/// The object.
/// </param>
private void DeleteObjectAndChildren(Object parent)
{
    // Deletes One-to-Many Children
    if (parent.Things != null && parent.Things.Count > 0)
    {
        this.db.Things.RemoveRange(parent.Things);
    }

    // Deletes Self Referenced Children
    if (parent.Children != null && parent.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var child in parent.Children)
        {
            this.DeleteObjectAndChildren(child);
        }

        this.db.Objects.RemoveRange(parent.Children);
    }
}
```