# Remove child records from aggregate root using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-6, aggregateroot

My customer business object is an aggregate root for a collection of addresses.

```
public class Customer {
  Public Customer {Addresses = new List<Address>}
  public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
  // other properties
}

Public class Address {
  public virtual Customer customer {get;set;}
  [NotMapped]

  // other properties
}
```

My context contains

```
public DBSet<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
```

but no DBSet for Address because I want the customer to be the aggregate root.

However when I use

```
Customer.Addresses.RemoveAll(x=>x.TaggedToDelete)
```

The Customer_Id in the Address table is set to null instead of the Address being removed from the database.

How do I remove the address from the database using the aggregate root?

I had a look at 
  [How to remove child one to many related records in EF code first database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654828/how-to-remove-child-one-to-many-related-records-in-ef-code-first-database)

but it uses a DBSet for the child record.

Answer (score 0):

```
var deleteQueue = customer.Addresses.Where(x => x.TaggedToDelete).ToArray();
 foreach (var a in deleteQueue)
 {
     var entry = connect.Entry(a);
     entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
 }
```