# Trying to understand deleting children entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to understand why Entity Framework works the way it does with deleting child entities!

I have a `YogaSpace` object/entity and a child entity called `YogaSpaceImage`. I want to delete a `YogaSpaceImage` from `YogaSpace`, so here is what I do.

This **DOES NOT** work

```
yogaSpace.Images.Remove(yogaSpaceImage);
```

to delete a child entity!

```
public string RemoveImage(int id, int imageIdToDelete)
{
        YogaSpace yogaSpace = _yogaSpaceRepository.Find(id);

        // delete image
        foreach (YogaSpaceImage yogaSpaceImage in yogaSpace.Images.OrderBy(m => m.Ordering))
        {
            if (yogaSpaceImage.YogaSpaceImageId == imageIdToDelete)
            {
                // check first to see if the deleted image is the first (primary) image, then make the 2nd image the yogaspace thumbnail
                if (yogaSpaceImage.Ordering == 1)
                {
                    yogaSpace.SpaceThumbnail = yogaSpace.Images.First(m => m.Ordering == 2).ImageThumbnail;
                }
                yogaSpace.Images.Remove(yogaSpaceImage);
            }
        } 
     }

     myRepository.InsertOrUpdate(YogaSpace);
     myRepository.Save()
}
```

This **does** work when I call `myRepo.Removed(YogaSpaceImage)`.

```
public string RemoveImage(int id, int imageIdToDelete)
{
        YogaSpace yogaSpace = _yogaSpaceRepository.Find(id);

        // delete image
        foreach (YogaSpaceImage yogaSpaceImage in yogaSpace.Images.OrderBy(m => m.Ordering))
        {
            if (yogaSpaceImage.YogaSpaceImageId == imageIdToDelete)
            {
                // check first to see if the deleted image is the first (primary) image, then make the 2nd image the yogaspace thumbnail
                if (yogaSpaceImage.Ordering == 1)
                {
                    yogaSpace.SpaceThumbnail = yogaSpace.Images.First(m => m.Ordering == 2).ImageThumbnail;
                }

                _yogaSpaceRepository.Removed(yogaSpaceImage);  
            }
        } 
     }

     myRepository.Save()
}
```

Here is what `Removed()` and `InsertOrUpdate()` look like in my repo.

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(YogaSpace yogaSpace)
{
        if (yogaSpace.YogaSpaceId == default(int))
        {
            context.Entry(yogaSpace).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(yogaSpace).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
}

public void Removed(YogaSpaceImage yogaSpaceImage)
{
        context.Entry(yogaSpaceImage).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

P.S. you would think `InsetOrUpdate()` in my repo would work for `EntityState.Modified` to remove a child entity?

P.P.S. not sure why I even need `InsertOrUpdate()`, it was built with the auto generated nuget package. If I don't use it and just call `Save()`, Entity Framework understands the changes I've made, so why the heck is it generated for me and why does `entity.Added` and `entity.Modified` even exist, because entities get saved and modified even if I don't explicitly calls these two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove child one to many related records in EF code first database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654828/how-to-remove-child-one-to-many-related-records-in-ef-code-first-database)

Answer (score 3):

A nice little trick is to use the parent's id in the child's primary key:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set;}
}
```

And the configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Children)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.ParentId})
            .Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

This way when you remove a child from the parent, the ParentId cannot be empty and EF will mark the child for deletion.

Example how to add/remove child to parent:

```
using(var db = new DbContext())
{
    var p = db.Parents.First();
    var c = new Child();
    p.Children.Add(c);
    db.SaveChanges(); // Child was saved to the database

    p.Children.Remove(c);
    db.SaveChanges(); // Child will be deleted from the database

    p.Children.Clear();
    db.SaveChanges(); // All Child of this parent will be deleted
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with attributes? I'm not using your system (can't remember the name) for defining relationships and keys. Just a side note, I do have a ref id to the parent entity. I define it in my object like  [Index]
        public int YogaSpaceRefId { get; set; }[ForeignKey("YogaSpaceRefId")]
        public virtual YogaSpace YogaSpace { get; set; }   and public virtual ICollection<YogaSpaceImage> Images { get; set; }