# context.Children missing from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm following this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654828/how-to-remove-child-one-to-many-related-records-in-ef-code-first-database) to delete all children from a parent entity, but intellisense doesn't find 'Children, there is a red line under it and I'm using EF 6.1

```
using (var dbContext = new Context())
        {
            dbContext.Children.RemoveRange
        }
```

Comment: Children is that question is a set of entities. So, they have a database table named Children (for example).

Comment: Oh I see. I got it!